# How to get LinqPad to work with "Dynamic Query"?

Tags: c#, linqpad, dynamicquery

[Dynamic Query](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) is a single C# file you add to your project.  Anyone know how to add this library so that it works with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile it into an assembly and then add a reference to that assembly.

From the LINQPad [FAQ](http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx):

> Customization & Extensibility
>
> What extensibility points does LINQPad provide?
>
> First, you can reference custom assemblies and import custom namespaces - go to Query Properties (F4).